# Why can't I review changes made to Sanity’s UI interface locally

Tags: content-management-system

I am trying to update old data made on Sanity for a website that I am working on. I want to review the changes that I have made - I ran npm run start however I keep getting this pop up:

Unauthorized
You are not authorized to access this studio. Maybe you could ask someone to invite you to collaborate on this project?
If you think this is an error, verify that you are logged in with the correct account. You are currently logged in as (my name)

Although I have been given access to the project, this error message persists. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried:
Backup your local config file, and remove it from your project’s working directory. Download the attached encrypted config file and move it into your project’s working directory as .env.asc. Run the following command, and it will generate a new .env in your project.

I also tried:
Check out develop branch
Make sure you are up to date with a git pull
Make sure you're running node 18 with node -v
Make sure all dependencies are installed and up to date with npm install
Make sure you launching the app with npm run dev